# Темы для .NET

Tags: .net

Вот для дельфи есть альфа скины. А для программ на net (mvs) есть что-то похожее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для программ на WPF (а это подмножество .NET) существуют стандартные темы - [WPF Themes](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home) - (при желании можно создавать свои, например, в Expression Blend).